# Angular ngRoute - not load the html correctly

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to use `ngRoute`.
when I go to url `/#/page1` I recive the `page1` in the correct place.
But I have a problem with the links, and also the css dont works correctly.
On the other hand if I go to `page1.html` and add the `css` and `js` of `mdl` it works ok.

This is my app

```
 var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider',
function ($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
  .when('/page1',{
     templateUrl : 'pages/page1.html',
     controller : 'Page1Ctrl'
   }); 

}])
.controller('Page1Ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){
}]);
```

my `page1.html` is the tabs lay out from `mdl` (The css and all  the js of `mdl` is in the `index.html`)

```
<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
      <a href="#starks-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab is-active">Starks</a>
      <a href="#lannisters-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Lannisters</a>
      <a href="#targaryens-panel" class="mdl-tabs__tab">Targaryens</a>
  </div>

  <div class="mdl-tabs__panel is-active" id="starks-panel">
    <ul>
      <li>Eddard</li>
      <li>Catelyn</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-tabs__panel" id="lannisters-panel">
    <ul>
      <li>Tywin</li>
      <li>Cersei</li>
      <li>Jamie</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-tabs__panel" id="targaryens-panel">
    <ul>
      <li>Viserys</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And in the `index.html` I add  `<ng-view ></ng-view>`

I try to use also jquery.load to load page1.html and the same problem.

I will thanks if someone can help me,

Thanks.

EDIT:
It's load the css but some of the css fields are overloaded.. so it looks like no css loaded..

Comment: Simply you cannot load the js & css references from partials..

Comment: So how can I make like a template to my site that changes the inner div that I dont have to load js,css in every html..?

Comment: Are you sure the CSS and JS files that are to be used on page1.html are being loaded in the index.html? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no error in the console. If i copy the code of the page1.html and replace it with the   <ng-view ></ng-view> everything works..

Comment: But if I copy the link to the css file to the pager1.html it not work

Comment: t's load the css but some of the css fields are overloaded.. so it looks like no css loaded..

Answer (score 0):

In `index.html` list all your resources `(js,css)` .

Within body tag of `index.html` create

```
ng-view
```

now all our partials html will be loaded in `ng-view`

**Note : do not forget to add `ng-app` in index.html**

**Update : Just change your router to**

```
  $routeProvider
  .when('/page1',{
     templateUrl : 'pages/page1.html',
     controller : 'Page1Ctrl'
   })
  .when('/',{
     templateUrl : 'pages/page1.html',
     controller : 'Page1Ctrl'
 });
```

Comment: I did it.. this is not load the css,js to the page1.html...This is the problem.. I see the page but it seems that the js file that in  index.html dont influence on page1.html

Comment: what is the url you trying to load,is it suffixed with /choose ?

Comment: t's load the css but some of the css fields are overloaded.. so it looks like no css loaded..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this: https://github.com/door3/angular-css. It allows you to specify css file(s) for each route.